# Add icon to show desktop

Tags: icons, show-desktop, minimize

I need the icon to minimize windows and show desktop. I can't find a decent guide. Can you help me?

Comment: Could you be more specific with your question? Apart from the icon, you first need the command to minimize all windows, am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

The first step, install `wmctrl` package:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

Description from the [wmctrl homepage](http://tripie.sweb.cz/utils/wmctrl/):

> The wmctrl program is a UNIX/Linux command line tool to interact with
>   an EWMH/NetWM compatible X Window Manager. The tool provides command
>   line access to almost all the features defined in the EWMH
>   specification. It can be used, for example, to obtain information
>   about the window manager, to get a detailed list of desktops and
>   managed windows, to switch and resize desktops, to make windows
>   full-screen, always-above or sticky, and to activate, close, move,
>   resize, maximize and minimize them. The command line access to these
>   window management functions makes it easy to automate and execute them
>   from any application that is able to run a command in response to an
>   event.

Next step, download and install script, [prepared by me](https://github.com/png2378/showdesktop):

```
cd /tmp && wget https://github.com/png2378/showdesktop/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip && cd showdesktop-master
sudo mv showdesktop /usr/local/bin/ && sudo mv showdesktop.desktop /usr/share/applications/ && sudo mv showdesktop.svg /usr/share/icons/elementary/apps/48/
```

The finish step, add icon on Plank:

```
mv showdesktop.dockitem ~/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Plank(Dock) has a hidden settings window for developers/OEMs.

1. Hold <kbd>Control</kbd> and right click anywhere on the dock
2. Select "Preferences"
3. Select "Docklets" tab from the Dialog box that appeared
4. Drag "Desktop" item to the Dock

Boom!!

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are asking how to minimize active windows in elementary?

As of now, there isnt a dedicated minimize button on application windows in elementary. You can, however, minimize active windows to plank (the dock) by clicking said application's icon in the dock.

Comment: You should really wait for the OP to clear up his question before posting an answer, which by the way seems to be missing the point.

Comment: Duly noted, I couldnt comment at the time due to no rep, but will keep this in mind for future questions.